# Parameter with that position [5] did not exist;

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to request some data in my database via a query, but all I get is this exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [5] did
not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [5]
did not exist
```

Well and this is my my MappingController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vacChange", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changedVac(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Integer id,
                         @RequestParam(value = "ort", required = true) String ort,
                         @RequestParam(value = "bereich", required = true) String bereich,
                         @RequestParam(value = "beschreibung", required = true) String beschreibung){
vacService.changeVacancyByID(id,gehalt,ort,bereich,beschreibung);


    return "vacAdmin";
}
```

I think I don't need to write down the ServiceClass but below is the ServiceClassImplementation

```
public void changeVacancyByID(Integer id, String gehalt,String ort,String bereich,String beschreibung){
        System.out.println("Edit method called");
        VacancyEntity vacEntity = vacancyRepository.findOneById(id);
        vacancyRepository.updateAttributes(id,gehalt,ort,bereich,beschreibung);

}
```

Last but not least this is my repository:

```
@Transactional
@Query (value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?1, location=?2,functionality=?3, description=?4 WHERE id = ?0  ", nativeQuery = true)
VacancyEntity updateAttributes(Integer id, String gehalt, String ort, String bereich, String beschreibung);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Position based parameters start with 1, try with this

```
@Query (value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?1, location=?2,functionality=?3, description=?4 WHERE id = ?5  ", nativeQuery = true)
VacancyEntity updateAttributes(String gehalt, String ort, String bereich, String beschreibung, Integer id);
```

or, with unchanged method signature

```
@Query (value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?2, location=?3,functionality=?4, description=?5 WHERE id = ?1  ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Ah thanks it seems that it solves the problem, but now i get a " could not extract ResultSet" exception

Comment: Seems unrelated to this problem, you should post a new question with relevant data (exception) in order to get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

From this [reference](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native) (emphasis is mine):

> Parameters to SQL queries are delimited using the ? character. Only indexed parameters are supported, named parameters are not supported. The index can be used in the delimiter, i.e. ?1. Parameter values are set on the Query using the setParameter API. **Indexed parameters start at the index 1 not 0.**

So you have to change your query to:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?2, location=?3,functionality=?4, description=?5 WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

see also, this [tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html#bnbri)